# How to divide a numpy array elementwise by another numpy array of lower dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array `[[0,1],[3,4],[5,6]]` and want to divide it elementwise by `[1,2,0]`.
The desired result will be `[[0,1],[1.5,2],[0,0]]`. So if the division is by zero, then the result is zero.  I only found a way to do it in pandas dataframe with div command, but couldn't find it for numpy arrays and conversion to dataframe does not seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your operation with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign the invalid values to `0`:

```
>>> np.where(d[:,None], x/d[:,None], 0)

array([[0. , 1. ],
       [1.5, 2. ],
       [0. , 0. ]])
```

This will still raise a warning though because we're not avoiding the division by zero:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: 
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in `true_divide`
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

A better way is to provide a mask to [`np.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) with the `where` argument:

```
>>> np.divide(x, d[:,None], where=d[:,None] != 0)
array([[0. , 1. ],
       [1.5, 2. ],
       [0. , 0. ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out this solution:

```
[list(x/y) if y != 0 else len(x)*[0,] for x, y in zip(a1, a2)]
```